# Customized Data View Forms with Content Types

Tags: sharepoint-designer, content-type, data-view-web-part, list-form

I have a list with 2 content types attached. I need to customize the new item form for both content types using SharePoint Designer customizations. The default content type works great and submits the data as expected. The secondary content type is not recognized and the new content is submitted as the default content type. I have attempted to explicitly set it and is still does not work.

Thanks!

Comment: The content types inherit from one another. The default content type is the parent and the secondary content type is the child. There are two field differences between the two content types.

Answer (score 1):

After a little investigation with my team, we determined that the way to overcome this problem is to simply pass the content type ID in the query string to the form.

```
http://[server]/lists/[list]/customnewform.aspx?**ContentTypeId=[id]**
```

Hopefully this will help someone else who is having the same problem.